# What is the difference between tinyint, smallint, mediumint, bigint and int in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, integer

What is the difference between tinyint, smallint, mediumint, bigint and int in MySQL?

In what cases should these be used?

Answer (score 647, accepted):

They take up different amounts of space and they have different ranges of acceptable values.

[Here are the sizes and ranges of values for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0), other RDBMSes have similar documentation:

- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)
- [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC)
- [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209) (they just have a `NUMBER` datatype really)
- [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db29.doc.intro/db2z_numericdatatypes.htm)

Turns out they all use the same specification (with a few minor exceptions noted below) but support various combinations of those types (Oracle not included because it has just a `NUMBER` datatype, see the above link):

```
             | SQL Server    MySQL   Postgres    DB2
---------------------------------------------------
tinyint      |     X           X                
smallint     |     X           X         X        X
mediumint    |                 X
int/integer  |     X           X         X        X 
bigint       |     X           X         X        X
```

And they support the same value ranges (with one exception below) and all have the same storage requirements:

```
            | Bytes    Range (signed)                               Range (unsigned)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tinyint     | 1 byte   -128 to 127                                  0 to 255
smallint    | 2 bytes  -32768 to 32767                              0 to 65535
mediumint   | 3 bytes  -8388608 to 8388607                          0 to 16777215
int/integer | 4 bytes  -2147483648 to 2147483647                    0 to 4294967295
bigint      | 8 bytes  -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807  0 to 18446744073709551615
```

The "unsigned" types are only available in MySQL, and the rest just use the signed ranges, with one notable exception: **`tinyint` in SQL Server is unsigned** and has a value range of 0 to 255

Comment: I didn't know that unsigned types are available only in MySQL, this is a huge advantage of MySQL over other RDBMS. Anything changed since the day this answer posted?

Comment: @Daniel, What are they thinking, why is there one for 3 bytes but none for 6 bytes?

Comment: @Pacerier probably they didn't know how to name it :))

Answer (score 42):

The **size of storage** required and **how big** the numbers can be.

On SQL Server:

- `tinyint`  1 byte, 0 to 255
- `smallint` 2 bytes, -2<sup>15</sup> (-32,768) to 2<sup>15</sup> -1 (32,767)
- `int` 4 bytes, -2<sup>31</sup> (-2,147,483,648) to 2<sup>31</sup> -1 (2,147,483,647)
- `bigint` 8 bytes, -2<sup>63</sup> (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2<sup>63</sup> -1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

You can store the number 1 in all 4, but a `bigint` will use 8 bytes, while a `tinyint` will use 1 byte.

Answer (score 22):

Those seem to be MySQL data types.

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) they take:

1. `tinyint` = 1 byte
2. `smallint` = 2 bytes
3. `mediumint` = 3 bytes
4. `int` = 4 bytes
5. `bigint` = 8 bytes

And, naturally, accept increasingly larger ranges of numbers.

Answer (score 12):

When it gets to real world usage of these datatypes, it is very important that you understand that using certain integer types could just be an overkill or under used. For example, using integer datatype for employeeCount in a table say employee could be an overkill since it supports a range of integer values from ~ negative 2 billion to positive 2 billion or zero to approximately 4 billion (unsigned). So, even if you consider one of the US biggest employer such as Walmart with roughly about 2.2 million employees using an integer datatype for the employeeCount column would be unnecessary. In such a case you use mediumint (that supports from 0 to 16 million (unsigned)) for example. Having said that if your range is expected to be unusually large you might consider bigint which as you can see from Daniel's notes supports a range larger than I care to decipher.

Comment: In your example of WalMart with 2.2M active employees - I would think that with staff turnover of approx 50% annually that an INT type on EmployeeID would be the minimum needed.  What do you'all think?

Granted - for MOST normal companies an INT type would be WAY overkill!

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the amount of memory allocated to each integer, and how large a number they each can store.

Answer (score 2):

Data type   Range   Storage

```
bigint  -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)    8 Bytes
int -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)    4 Bytes
smallint    -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)  2 Bytes
tinyint 0 to 255    1 Byte
```

**Example**

The following example creates a table using the bigint, int, smallint, and tinyint data types. Values are inserted into each column and returned in the SELECT statement.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
  MyBigIntColumn bigint
 ,MyIntColumn  int
 ,MySmallIntColumn smallint
 ,MyTinyIntColumn tinyint
);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES (9223372036854775807, 214483647,32767,255);
 GO
SELECT MyBigIntColumn, MyIntColumn, MySmallIntColumn, MyTinyIntColumn
FROM dbo.MyTable;
```