# Why unsigned integer is not available in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, unsigned-integer

I came across this post ([What is the difference between tinyint, smallint, mediumint, bigint and int in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991405/what-is-the-difference-between-tinyint-smallint-mediumint-bigint-and-int-in-s)) and realized that PostgreSQL does not support unsigned integer.

Can anyone help to explain why is it so?

Most of the time, I use unsigned integer as auto incremented primary key in MySQL. In such design, how can I overcome this when I port my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL?

Thanks.

Comment: Not yet but soon and we are considering to move to PostgreSQL.

Comment: I don't think this is the best place to be asking why certain decisions were made, one of the PostgreSQL mailing lists might be more suitable. If you want auto-incrementing values then use `serial` (1 to 2147483647) or `bigserial` (1 to 9223372036854775807). A signed 64bit integer probably offers more than enough room.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort. That answered the primary key issue.

But how about an unsigned integer type which is not auto incremented nor primary key? I do have columns which store unsigned integer which has a range from 0 to 2^32.

Comment: A quick run through the PostgreSQL docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/index.html) might be useful to help you get a better idea of what PostgreSQL is capable of. The only reason I'd use MySQL these days is if I already had a lot invested in it: PostgreSQL is fast, loaded with useful features, and built by people that are pretty paranoid about their data. IMO of course :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It is already answered why postgresql lacks unsigned types. However I would suggest to use domains for unsigned types.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createdomain.html

```
 CREATE DOMAIN name [ AS ] data_type
    [ COLLATE collation ]
    [ DEFAULT expression ]
    [ constraint [ ... ] ]
 where constraint is:
 [ CONSTRAINT constraint_name ]
 { NOT NULL | NULL | CHECK (expression) }
```

Domain is like a type but with an additional constraint.

For an concrete example you could use

```
CREATE DOMAIN uint2 AS int4
   CHECK(VALUE >= 0 AND VALUE < 65536);
```

Here is what psql gives when I try to abuse the type.

> DS1=# select (346346 :: uint2);
>
> ERROR:  value for domain uint2 violates check constraint "uint2_check"

Comment: But I guess that using this domain every time we want an unsigned column would have an overhead on INSERT/UPDATE. Better to use this where it is really necessary (which is rare) and just get used to the idea that the datatype doesn't put the lower limit we desire. After all, it also puts an upper limit which is usually meaningless from a logical point of view. Numeric types are not design to enforce our applications constraints.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that you are "wasting" 15 bits of data storage which are unused. Not to mention the check also costs some small amount of efficiency. The better solution would be Postgres adding unsigned as a first class type. In a table with 20 million records, with and indexed field like this, you are wasting 40MB of space on unused bits. If you are abusing that across another 20 tables, you're now wasting 800MB of space.

Answer (score 140):

It's not in the SQL standard, so the general urge to implement it is lower.

Having too many different integer types makes the type resolution system more fragile, so there is some resistance to adding more types into the mix.

That said, there is no reason why it couldn't be done.  It's just a lot of work.

Comment: This question is popular enough that I have set out to get it fixed: https://github.com/petere/pguint

Comment: Having input/output conversions for unsigned integer literals would be super useful though. Or even just a `to_char` pattern.

Comment: Is this also explains why we don't have tinyint in postgres? (which sometimes may be more efficient supposed we know the value fits in the range)

Answer (score 48):

You can use a CHECK constraint, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id integer,
    name text,
    price numeric CHECK (price > 0)
);
```

Also, PostgreSQL has `serial`, `smallserial` and `bigserial` types for auto-increment.

Comment: One thing to mention, you can't have any NULLs in columns that use CHECK.

Comment: @Minutis are you sure you cant have x IS NULL OR x BETWEEN 4 AND 40

Comment: And this doesn't give you same resolution as it would if it was unsigned int. Meaning unsigned int could go up to `2^32-1`, meanwhile signed ints can go up to`2^31-1`.

Comment: `NULL` and `CHECK` are completely orthogonal. You can have `NULL`/`NOT NULL` columns with or without `CHECK`. Just note that, as per the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html, `CHECK` returning NULL evaluates to TRUE, so if you really wants to prevent NULLs, then use `NOT NULL` instead (or in addition to `CHECK`).

Comment: using a CHECK doesn't allow me to store ipv4 addresses in `integer` (not without having them go randomly positive or negative, at least..)

Answer (score 36):

The talk about DOMAINS is interesting but not relevant to the only possible origin of that question. The desire for unsigned ints is to double the range of ints with the same number of bits, it's an efficiency argument, not the desire to exclude negative numbers, everybody knows how to add a check constraint.

When [asked by someone about it](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAEcSYX+Arn7y4FeYPp6ZgbiiiMfZYmsn9aUyotZB-MA1n5hTOw@mail.gmail.com), Tome Lane stated:

> Basically, there is zero chance this will happen unless you can find
>   a way of fitting them into the numeric promotion hierarchy that doesn't
>   break a lot of existing applications.  We have looked at this more than
>   once, if memory serves, and failed to come up with a workable design
>   that didn't seem to violate the POLA.

What is the "POLA"? [Google gave me 10 results that are meaningless](https://www.google.com/search?oq=PostgreSQL%20%22POLA%22%20). Not sure if it's politically incorrect thought and therefore censored. Why would this search term not yield any result? Whatever.

You can implement unsigned ints as extension types without too much trouble. If you do it with C-functions, then there will be about no performance penalties at all. You won't need to extend the parser to deal with literals because PgSQL has such an easy way to interpret strings as literals, just write '4294966272'::uint4 as your literals. Casts shouldn't be a huge deal either. You don't even need to do range exceptions, you can just treat the semantics of '4294966273'::uint4::int as -1024. Or you can throw an error.

If I wanted this, I would have done it. But since I'm using Java on the other side of SQL, to me it is of little value since Java doesn't have those unsigned integers either. So I gain nothing. I'm already annoyed if I get a BigInteger from a bigint column, when it should fit into long.

Another thing, if I did have the need to store 32 bit or 64 bit types, I can use PostgreSQL int4 or int8 respectively, just remembering that the natural order or arithmetic won't work reliably. But storing and retrieving is unaffected by that.

---

Here is how I can implement a simple unsigned int8:

First I will use

```
CREATE TYPE name (
    INPUT = uint8_in,
    OUTPUT = uint8_out
    [, RECEIVE = uint8_receive ]
    [, SEND = uint8_send ]
    [, ANALYZE = uint8_analyze ]
    , INTERNALLENGTH = 8
    , PASSEDBYVALUE ]
    , ALIGNMENT = 8
    , STORAGE = plain
    , CATEGORY = N
    , PREFERRED = false
    , DEFAULT = null
)
```

the minimal 2 functions `uint8_in` and `uint8_out` I must first define.

```
CREATE FUNCTION uint8_in(cstring)
    RETURNS uint8
    AS 'uint8_funcs'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE FUNCTION uint64_out(complex)
    RETURNS cstring
    AS 'uint8_funcs'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

need to implement this in C uint8_funcs.c. So I go use [the complex example from here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/xtypes.html) and make it simple:

```
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(complex_in);

Datum complex_in(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    char       *str = PG_GETARG_CSTRING(0);
    uint64_t   result;

    if(sscanf(str, "%llx" , &result) != 1)
        ereport(ERROR,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_TEXT_REPRESENTATION),
                 errmsg("invalid input syntax for uint8: \"%s\"", str)));

    return (Datum)SET_8_BYTES(result);
}
```

ah well, or you can [just find it done already](https://github.com/petere/pguint).

Comment: I'm guessing POLA is the "principle of least astonishment". It suggests that the change has the potential to change existing behaviour in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 4):

According to the latest documentation, the signed integer is supported but no unsigned integer in the table. However, the serial type is kind of similar to unsigned except it starts from 1 not from zero. But the upper limit is the same as signed. So the system truly does not have unsigned support. As pointed out by Peter, the door is open to implement the unsigned version.  The code may have to be updated a lot, just too much work from my experience working with C programming.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-numeric.html

```
integer     4 bytes     typical choice for integer  -2147483648 to +2147483647
serial      4 bytes     autoincrementing integer    1 to 2147483647
```

Answer (score 4):

Postgres does have an unsigned integer type that is unbeknownst to many: [**`OID`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-oid.html).

> The `oid` type is currently implemented as an unsigned four-byte integer. […]
>
> The `oid` type itself has few operations beyond comparison. It can be
>   cast to integer, however, and then manipulated using the standard
>   integer operators. (Beware of possible signed-versus-unsigned confusion
>   if you do this.)

It is not a [numeric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT) though, and trying to do any arithmetic (or even bitwise operations) with it is going to fail. Also, it's just 4 bytes (`INTEGER`), there is no corresponding 8 byte (`BIGINT`) unsigned type.

So it's not really a good idea to use this yourself, and I agree with all the other answers that in a Postgresql database design you should always use an `INTEGER` or `BIGINT` column for your [serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) primary key - having it start in the negative (`MINVALUE`) or allowing it to wrap around (`CYCLE`) if you want to exhaust the full domain.

However, it is quite useful for input/output conversion, like your migration from another DBMS. Inserting the value `2147483648` into an integer column will lead to an "*ERROR:  integer out of range*", while using the expression `2147483648::OID` works just fine.
Similarly, when selecting an integer column as text with `mycolumn::TEXT`, you will get negative values at some point, but with `mycolumn::OID::TEXT` you will always get a natural number.

See [an example at dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0304a634bc420bd38d9154aebbad8b32).

Comment: If you don't need operations, then the only value from using OID is that your sort order works. If that is what you need, fine. But soon someone will want a uint8 and then they are lost too.

The bottom line is that to store 32 bit or 64 bit values you can just use int4 and int8 respectively, just need  to be careful with the operations. But it is easy to write an extension.