# How do I store an unsigned int in postgres sql?

Tags: postgresql

How do I store an unsigned int (uint32) in postgres? I noticed that numeric(10,0) would fit the number of digits, but is this the best way?

On further research another similar problem is storing a uint64. I've found numeric(20,0) check (BETWEEN 0 AND '18446744073709551615'::numeric(20,0)). There aren't any native types for this I believe.

Comment: Have a look at [Why unsigned integer is not available in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20810134/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arithmetic on numeric values is very slow compared to the integer types.

Use [`bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-INT). It stores an 8 byte integer up to `2^63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807`

[You probably don't need the entire unsigned range]

Comment: I want to store the exact unsigned value.. So bigint is faster than numeric(10,0) check (value >= 0 and value < '4294967296'::numeric(10,0))?

Comment: @Fire Much, much faster. You still need the check constraint.

Comment: So `bigint check (value >= 0 and value < '4294967296'::bigint)`

Comment: What if you're trying to store an unsigned Int64... and actually need the whole unsigned range?