# JPA/Hibernate (PSQL) does not create joinedtable

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

For some reason Hibernate does not create tables for Collections,
below listed the code
BaseEntity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED")
    protected Long id;
    @Column(name = "version")
    @Version
    private Long version;
```

here are two other classes that inherits from BaseEntity

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "route_id",
        nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED"))
public class Route extends BaseEntityAudit {

    @ElementCollection
    private Collection<Point> routePoints = new ArrayList<Point>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "route_events")
    private Collection<Event> routeEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "route_comments")
    private Collection<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "event_id",
        nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED"))
public class Event extends BaseEntityAudit {
    @Embedded
    private Point point;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "event_comments")
    private Collection<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
```

the persistence.xml already has this property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

my log

```
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "event_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table event_comments drop constraint FK_11571d99a3cf411d9164940b877
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "event_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_comments drop constraint FK_f8a59d97d3374c8385789cfba60
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_comments drop constraint FK_513ae6d743c64d92ae0081d522d
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_events drop constraint FK_65c26cfb67b342b081f210e4550
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_events" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_events drop constraint FK_feed651c8fdc4dc2bf274715db3
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_events" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table Route_routePoints (Route_route_id BIGINT UNSIGNED not null, latitude float8, longitude float8)
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNSIGNED"
  Position: 55
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table event_comments (Event_event_id BIGINT UNSIGNED not null, comments_id BIGINT UNSIGNED not null)
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNSIGNED"
  Position: 52
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table route_comments (Route_route_id BIGINT UNSIGNED not null, comments_id BIGINT UNSIGNED not null)
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNSIGNED"
  Position: 52
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table route_events (Route_route_id BIGINT UNSIGNED not null, routeEvents_event_id BIGINT UNSIGNED not null)
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNSIGNED"
  Position: 50
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Route_routePoints add constraint FK_4e53fd400f6447a985cc918eca4 foreign key (Route_route_id) references Route
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_routepoints" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table event_comments add constraint UK_dd004f7aa4cc492a8fdbba97cb5 unique (comments_id)
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "event_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table event_comments add constraint FK_4c93abd961304742bd47c55dcc1 foreign key (comments_id) references Comment
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "event_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table event_comments add constraint FK_11571d99a3cf411d9164940b877 foreign key (Event_event_id) references Event
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "event_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_comments add constraint UK_7fe905828f9d4dce993484493a7 unique (comments_id)
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_comments add constraint FK_f8a59d97d3374c8385789cfba60 foreign key (comments_id) references Comment
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_comments add constraint FK_513ae6d743c64d92ae0081d522d foreign key (Route_route_id) references Route
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_comments" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_events add constraint UK_42dd851c0e9a467e9911fab1caf unique (routeEvents_event_id)
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_events" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_events add constraint FK_65c26cfb67b342b081f210e4550 foreign key (routeEvents_event_id) references Event
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_events" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table route_events add constraint FK_feed651c8fdc4dc2bf274715db3 foreign key (Route_route_id) references Route
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_events" does not exist
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
Jul 22, 2015 2:42:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: relation "route_events" does not exist
  Position: 13

javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)
    at home.map.events.dao.daoImpl.DAOUtils.add(DAOUtils.java:15)
    at home.map.events.dao.daoImpl.RouteDaoImpl.addRoute(RouteDaoImpl.java:16)
    at home.map.events.dao.daoImpl.RouteDaoImplTest.start(RouteDaoImplTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:80)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1256)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "route_events" does not exist
  Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    ... 34 more
```

When I check PG admin missed tables such as route_events are not there.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should focus on "syntax error at or near "UNSIGNED"" in connection with Postgresql.

[Why unsigned integer is not available in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810134/why-unsigned-integer-is-not-available-in-postgresql)

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA+TgmoY0h-hFG-SpZoMMNEEi=VXiEtpMjsAfwgBCoNPCjPMB+Q@mail.gmail.com

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you :)