# How to store unsigned long in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

There is [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810134/why-unsigned-integer-is-not-available-in-postgresql/20850942) about why there is no unsigned integer (32 bit) and the answer was because it is not an SQL standard and the solution was [using domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31833279/455796). Basically the answer was using a 32-bit signed integer and restricting it to a 16-bit unsigned integer range.

But what if I want an unsigned long integer (64 bit)? There do not seem to exist int9 or int16.

```
create domain uint8 as int16 check(value>=0 and value<18446744073709551615)
```

> ERROR:  type "int16" does not exist 
>  SQL state: 42704

Comment: `18446744073709551615` doesn't fit in a bigint, so you will have to use `numeric`