# Should MEDIUMINT be avoided in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I came across a comment on the following blogpost that recommends against using `MEDIUMINT`:

> Don’t use [the 24bit INT], even in MySQL. It’s dumb, and it’s slow, and the code that implements it is a crawling horror.

[4294967295 and MySQL INT(20) Syntax Blows](http://laughingmeme.org/2010/01/24/4294967295-and-mysql-int20-syntax-blows/)

An answer on Stack Overflow also notes that SQL Server, PostgreSQL and DB2 don't support `MEDIUMINT`:

> [What is the difference between tinyint, smallint, mediumint, bigint and int in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991405/what-is-the-difference-between-tinyint-smallint-mediumint-bigint-and-int-in-m)

Should `MEDIUMINT` be avoided or should I continue to use it in the cases where it best represents the data I am storing?

Comment: It's false economy.  The natural width on modern processors is 32 or 64 bits, and the db has to go to extra effort to enforce 24-bit integer width.

Comment: @JimGarrison I really doubt that is much of a factor overall. It could be stored as 32-bits in-memory (or not but it doesn't really matter), and 24-bits on records trivially. (Saving up to 25% space over an int..)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

InnoDB stores MEDIUMINT as three bytes value.
But when MySQL has to do any computation the three bytes MEDIUMINT is converted into eight bytes unsigned long int(I assume nobody runs MySQL on 32 bits nowadays).

There are pros and cons, but you understand that "It’s dumb, and it’s slow, and the code that implements it is a crawling horror" reasoning is not technical, right?

I would say MEDIUMINT makes sense when data size on disk is critical. I.e. when a table has so many records that even one byte difference (4 bytes INT vs 3 bytes MEDIUMINT) means a lot. It's rather a rare case, but possible.

mach_read_from_3 and mach_read_from_4 - primitives that InnoDB uses to read numbers from InnoDB records are similar. They both return ulint. I bet you won't notice a difference on *any* workload.

Just take a look at the code:

```
ulint
mach_read_from_3(
/*=============*/
        const byte*     b)      /*!< in: pointer to 3 bytes */
{
        ut_ad(b);
        return( ((ulint)(b[0]) << 16)
                | ((ulint)(b[1]) << 8)
                | (ulint)(b[2])
                );
}
```

Do you think it's much slower than this?

```
ulint
mach_read_from_4(
/*=============*/
        const byte*     b)      /*!< in: pointer to four bytes */
{
        ut_ad(b);
        return( ((ulint)(b[0]) << 24)
                | ((ulint)(b[1]) << 16)
                | ((ulint)(b[2]) << 8)
                | (ulint)(b[3])
                );
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I was looking to confirm if there was anything particularly bad about the way that MySQL handles the mediumint internally, or if it was really non-standard and should be avoided. It sounds like it is fine to use if it fits the data being stored.

Comment: Hi, you mean, if i use this: `min(MEDIUMINTField)` in MySQL, the result will be eight bytes and in java, for example, i need a `long` type variable ?

Comment: It's up to a client library to decide which type to use for the result.

Answer (score 4):

In the grand scheme of things, fetching a row is the big cost.  Simple functions, expressions, and much less, data formats, is insignificant in how long a query takes.

On the other side, if your dataset it too large to stay cached, the overhead of I/O to fetch row(s) is even more significant.  A crude rule of thumb says that a non-cached row takes 10 *times* as long as a cached one.  Hence, shrinking the dataset (such as using a smaller `*INT`) *may* give you a huge performance benefit.

This argument apples to `...INT`, `FLOAT` vs `DOUBLE`, `DECIMAL(m,n)`, `DATETIME(n)`, etc.  (A different discussion is needed for `[VAR]CHAR/BINARY(...)` and `TEXT/BLOB`.)

For those with a background in Assembly language...

- A table is *likely* to have a mixture of numbers and strings, thereby thwarting attempts to "align" values.
- MySQL has always handled a variety of hardwares (big/little-endian, 16/32/64-bit) *with binary compatibility*.  Note how the code @akuzminsky provided avoids alignment and endian issues.  And it lets the compiler deal with 32-bit issues if the hardware is only 16-bit.
- The code to test for special cases would probably outweigh the simply writing generic code.
- We are talking typically less than 1% of the total row-handling time.

Hence, the only sane way to write the code is to work at the byte level, and to ignore register size and assume all values are mis-aligned.

For Optimization, in order of importance:

1. Count the disk hits.  Touching disk is overwhelmingly the most costly part of a query.
2. Count the number of rows touched.  Finding a row (via BTree, etc) takes some CPU.  But, note, very few installations are CPU-bound; those that are tend to have poor indexes.  (Rule of Thumb:  There are typically 100 rows in an InnoDB data or index block.)
3. Only now does parsing the row come into play.

Rule of Thumb:  If a tentative optimization does not (via back-of-envelope calc) yield 10% improvement, don't waste your time on it.  Instead look for some bigger improvement.  For example, indexes and Summary tables are often provide 10x (not just 10%).

Comment: Thanks, and what about a MySQL `MEDIUMINT` (3 bytes) integer? will it cause the CPU to do extra work to align the data on the registers ? that is what I have been told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053088/how-much-size-i-will-save-if-changed-int-column-to-mediumint)

Comment: @Accountantم - My background is such that I very much understand "word alignment".  But, I claim, it is truly insignificant in this context.  I added a bunch to my Answer.