# Convert large string to bigInteger and pass it to prepared statement

Tags: java, groovy, prepared-statement, biginteger

I have this string say `reference` = '`2039487894563827398440987`'

I am trying to convert it to BigInteger by doing something like

```
def reference = new BigInteger(reference)
```

and then in prepared statement I am setting it as

```
ps.setLong(reference);
```

The database `column(XYZ)` on which I am mapping this value has `dataType` `BigInt(40)`. But when I execute the statement it shows exception:

```
SQLSTATEEXCEPTION: Out of range value of column `XYZ` at row 1
```

How to deal with such situation.

**Edit**: Tried `setBigDecimal(reference);` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setBigDecimal() instead of setLong().

Comment: Might be worth noting that to use setBigDecimal, you'll need to convert the BigInteger to a BigDecimal i.e. ps.setBigDecimal(new BigDecimal(reference));

Comment: @JRichardSnape yes I have made sure of that.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is too large for a MySQL BIGINT column.  If you read [these docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//integer-types.html) - you see that the BIGINT data type cannot take such a large number (maximums are ±9223372036854775807 signed, or 18446744073709551615 unsigned).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2991419/838992) for a more comprehensive look through documentation - across different server types.

If you can change the type in the database, you might want to consider changing it to a NUMERIC field, or storing the number as a string, or converting it to a byte array and storing it as a binary blob.

***EDIT:***

For completeness - in case anyone is confused about what the `40` means in `BIGINT(40)`.  It means almost nothing.  It certainly doesn't affect the size of number stored - that's always 8 bytes (64 bits).  It is a hint to the database about how to display the number - i.e. display the first 40 digits.  It might affect zero padding - e.g. if you put values `123456789` and `5` into a `BIGINT(5)` column, they might well display as `123456789` and `00005`.  Check [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html) for other types available.

Note that the longest number a BigInt field can store is 20 digits long in base 10, so `40` really does mean almost nothing at all.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of the fact with BIGINT(40).
Its just I am wondering that isn't there any other way instead of changing dataType in DB

Comment: I think not, basically - because 2039487894563827398440987 > 18446744073709551615 - it just won't fit. You need another Data type if you're going to store numbers that big.