# MySQL: why is 'true' saved as 0?

Tags: mysql, swift, post, boolean, tinyint

I have a DB in MySQL where a column of my table is a boolean:

```
`eligibilityDate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
```

Data arrive from my iOS Swift app through the following functions:

```
let postParams = "action=save_report&id_fish=\(Reporting.fishId)&fish_name=\(Reporting.fishName)&detectedSize=\(Reporting.detectedSize)&eligibilitySize=\(Reporting.eligibilitySize)&eligibilityDate=\(Reporting.eligibilityDate)&origin=\(Reporting.origin)&production=\(Reporting.production)&townReport=\(Reporting.townReport)"

request.HTTPBody = postParams.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

where I guess that Bool variables `eligibilityDate` and `eligibilitySize` are converted from true/false to 'true'/'false'.
Anyway it seems that 'true' value is saved as 0 in MySQL...why? which is the correct way?

**UPDATE**

A possible solution could be this:

`let postParams = "action=save_report&id_fish=\(Reporting.fishId)&fish_name=\(Reporting.fishName)&detectedSize=\(Reporting.detectedSize)&eligibilitySize=\(Reporting.eligibilitySize ? 1 : 0)&eligibilityDate=\(Reporting.eligibilityDate ? 1 : 0)&origin=\(Reporting.origin)&production=\(Reporting.production)&townReport=\(Reporting.townReport)"`

Comment: Looks something wrong with request Try first with static value by putting &eligibilityDate=1. since eligibilityDate is tinyint(1) so for any other value from request in not in range (tinyint (1)) than it will insert 0 by deafult

Comment: it seems that with `eligibilityDate='1'` works correctly... I don't understand why with 'true' is converted to 0...

Comment: tinyint only accept integer value based on range(1 in your case). so if you pass true it will not convert to 1 but instead it will insert default integer value that is 0.

Comment: well, that is strange because I had done another project where the stored value was `tinyint` and I could freely use type `Bool` in the app...I don't know why it does not work anymore.

Comment: tinyint: 1 byte, -128 to +127 / 0 to 255 (unsigned) for more info  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991405/what-is-the-difference-between-tinyint-smallint-mediumint-bigint-and-int-in-m

Comment: this is not of help...